# Difference beetween pandas merge with how='outer' and pandas append

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given that I have the two following pandas `DataFrame`s:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['d', 'e', 'f'], 'C':[4,5,6]})
```

is there any difference between

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

and

```
df1.append(df2)
```

Although the resulting `DataFrame` is the same in both cases and despite the fact that on can merge on any arbitrary column, I was wondering if there is any advantage of using the one over another in such a specific case?

Comment: If the original index is matter , I will using append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important difference is the output dataframe's index.
`append` will keep the original index while `merge` reassigns a new index.
See that example :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3], "b": ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"c": [4,5,6], "b": ["epsilon", "delta", "omega"]})
df.append(df2)
```

Returns:

```
     a        b    c
0  1.0    alpha  NaN
1  2.0     beta  NaN
2  3.0    gamma  NaN
0  NaN  epsilon  4.0
1  NaN    delta  5.0
2  NaN    omega  6.0
```

While:

```
df.merge(df2, how="outer")
```

Returns:

```
     a        b    c
0  1.0    alpha  NaN
1  2.0     beta  NaN
2  3.0    gamma  NaN
3  NaN  epsilon  4.0
4  NaN    delta  5.0
5  NaN    omega  6.0
```